# Declaring multiple objects in class Perl

Tags: perl, oop, self

I have a problem and that is when I want to initialize two objects using the $ self variable. The first object will be initialized but the second will not. Here is some code:

```
     ###Class main
     use bar;
     use arg; 
     sub new{
          my $class = shift;
          my $args = shift;

          my $self = {};
          $self->{'foo'} = $class->SUPER->new($args);
          $self->{'bar'} = bar->new();
          bless($self, $class);
          return $self;
     }

   sub getFoo{
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{'foo'};
   }

    sub getBar{
         my $self = shift;
        return $self->{'bar'};

    }
```

For the function getFoo such it returns a value but for getBar the value returned is undef, why does this happen? Thanks

**EDIT1**
Yes, arg is class's parent and foo is a class that i want to use certain methods.

```
    ####class bar
    package bar;
    sub new{
      my $class = shift;
      my $self = {
          _bar1 => shift // 0,
          _bar2 => shift //0,
       };
      bless($self,$class);
      return $self;
    }

     sub getBar1{
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{_bar1};
     }
```

But if I do this now in my class main

```
    $self->{__bar}->getBar1;
```

The message return is : can´t call method "getBar1" on an undefined value.

Comment: The intent seems to be to assign to data in `$self` the following: the return of _constructors_ for (1) this class's parent (except it should be `$class->SUPER::new(...)`), and (2) for the class `bar`. Is this really what you mean?  Your `'foo'` and `'bar'` should then contain _objects_.  Next, you show neither the parent nor `bar` so it's hard to tell.  Can you clarify and add more code?

Comment: okey , i add more code zdim. Thanks!

Comment: You never declare a superclass, `$class->SUPER->new($args);` isn't going to work. Also, its bad form to use `package main` as a class.

Comment: If this is a subclass of `arg` (class names should start with a capital letter) then you need to put 'arg' into `@ISA` somehow. Also, if *"`foo` is a class that [you] want to use certain methods [from]"* then you need to `use foo` somewhere. Please rewrite your code so that it shows the symptoms you are talking about. We need to be able to run it ourselves.

Comment: Re "*Yes, arg is class's parent*", Not according to the code you showed

Comment: Re *"foo is a class that i want to use certain methods.*", `foo` doesn't appear anywhere in your code!

Comment: `$self->{'foo'} = $class->SUPER->new($args);` is crazy!

Comment: In the future, please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. It's hard to believe that's the you ran to get the output you got...

Answer (score 4):

You place the object in

```
$self->{bar}
```

then you call

```
$self->{__bar}->getBar1
```

Change that to

```
$self->{bar}->getBar1
```

---

You appear to have a number of other problems. From your description of your code, `Unnamed.pm` should contain something like the following: (Don't use `main`; that's already being used.)

```
package Unnamed;

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use foo qw( );
use bar qw( );

use parent 'arg';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $args = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($args);
    $self->{foo} = foo->new();
    $self->{bar} = bar->new();
    return $self;
}

sub get_foo {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{foo};
}

sub get_bar {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{bar};
}

1;
```

Then, you can do

```
my $o = Unnamed->new();
$o->get_bar->bar_method();
```